# Google MAPS API 3 LatLng values as an array

Tags: arrays, syntax, google-maps-api-3, polygon

**Bottomline is: how to create a polygon from 800 lat/lng values using arrays?**

I'm trying to pass LatLng value as an array element to

```
var paths = new Array();
var l = coords.length;
for (coords = 0; coords <= l; coords++){
    paths[x] = new google.maps.LatLng( coords[x][0], coords[x][1]);
}
```

No matter how try to loop over the array with coordinates it fails. I've tried different syntaxes, array formats, parseFloat, toFixed etc.

```
[["22.0","60.2"]["21.0","61.2"]]
[[22.0,60.2],[21.0,61.2]]
path = [my_arr[x][y]];
path = my_arr[x][y];
```

I've tried time-consuming "alert-debugging" and it seems that the used values are OK, but somehow the loop and arrays fail. Even if I get the arrays correct I won't be able use them in creating a polygon for a map.

If I use following syntax

```
var polygon_coords = [
new google.maps.LatLng(),
new google.maps.LatLng(),
....
];
```

it works. But since I have 800 of these lines it is a bit too much. And if I get the arrays correct should I use some kind of listener or so in order render the map only after all the LatLng functions are ready?

Comment: Replace `for (coords = 0; coords <= l; coords++){` with `for (var x= 0; x < l; x++){` and pass `path` as `Polygon`'s `paths` option.

Comment: @user1113426 No, wait, just realized the <= and <

Comment: Can you provide the structure of `coords` array?

Comment: @user1113426 YES, it did the trick! Thank you! I've been doing too much work lately and it is beginning to be too much, can't even see the obvious. Thanks again!